# サイトのナビゲーションで、選択されている箇所に背景色を付けたい。

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

サイトのナビゲーションなどによくある、選択されている箇所に背景色を付けたいのですが、
どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？
例えば以下の場合、会社案内をクリックしたとしたら、`<li>会社案内</li>`の背景色を赤色とかにしたいです。

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>会社案内</li>
  <li>製品一覧</li>
  <li>お問い合わせ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 「選択されている」とは、「マウスカーソルが載っている」とか「一度クリックした」とか具体的にどういう状況を指しますか？。あるいは「会社案内ページが表示されているときは会社案内メニューに色がついている」といった動きにしたいのでしょうか。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。やりたいのは「会社案内ページが表示されているときは会社案内メニューに色がついている」状態にしたいです。

Comment: それぞれのページが別々に用意されているのならばクリックでページが切り替わるようにリンクを作成しておきそのページで`<li style="background-color:red">会社案内</li>`のようにすればいいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クリックした時の動作をイベントハンドラとして登録しておく。

クリックした時の動作は、
cssとして`background-color`を書き換えてもいいが、
css は別に用意しておきクラス付け(例として`selected`とします）を変更することでcssを切り替える。
現在選択されている(`class='selected'`になっている)要素からクラスを取り除く
クリックした要素にクラス付けをする。

jQuery を利用した例：

```css
ul.nav li {
  background-color: transparent; /* default value */
}
ul.nav li.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("ul.nav li").click(function(){
      $("ul.nav li.selected").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
  });
</script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>会社案内</li>
  <li>製品一覧</li>
  <li>お問い合わせ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えていただいたことを実行したら、やりたかったことができました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 本件は教えて頂き誠にありがとうございました。大変申し訳ありませんが、テキストの色を変えるやり方もアドバイス頂けると助かります。何卒宜しくお願い致します。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33744/%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e3%83%8a%e3%83%93%e3%82%b2%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ae-%e9%81%b8%e6%8a%9e%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%ad%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%ab%e8%89%b2%e3%82%92%e4%bb%98%e3%81%91%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99

Comment: @poplot726  テキストの場合は`color: blue;` のようにcss で `color` を指定します。リンクの場合はリンクの状態それぞれについて指定します。 [参考](http://www.tagindex.com/stylesheet/link/color.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！colorに変更したらできました。
お手数おかけしました。m(_ _)m